# ajax call fails first 2 times and then returns success from 3rd time

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, webmethod

```
<button type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success" runat="server" onserverclick=`enter code here`"Submitbtn_ServerClick">Submit</button> 

<script>       
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%> ").click(function () {

            var Tabledata = new Array();

            $('#<%=AbsenceInfoTable.ClientID%> tr').each(function (row, tr) {

                console.log("entered each");
                Tabledata[row] = {
                    "DateOfAbsence": $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
                    "Reason": $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
                    "AdminAbsenceReason": $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text(),
                    "DayType": $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text()

                }
                console.log(Tabledata[row]);

            });

            Tabledata.shift(); //first row is the table header - so remove
            console.log("Just the Table Data" + Tabledata);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'table.aspx/GetAbsenceData',
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                data:  "{'items':" + JSON.stringify(Tabledata) + "}",
                success: function getSuccess() { alert("Success: "); },
                error: function getFail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert("Fail: " + jqXHR.status + "error : " + errorThrown.text) }

            });

        });

    });

</script>

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void GetAbsenceData(List<object> items)
    {}
```

The Json Object is generated correctly in all the cases. A postback is made when the submit button is clicked, erasing the previous inputs.

For first 2 times when submit button is clicked, Alert returns Fail: 0 Error: Undefined.

Then from the third time the alert box displays success.

I am not understanding the reason for this behavior. 
Thanks.

Comment: are you sure that console.log("Just the Table Data" + Tabledata); is printing same data 3 times?

Comment: I think I didn't explained in the right manner above. When I click submit for the first time, returns error. Clicking Ok on the alert box refreshes the page. Again I fill some input and clicking submit gives error as in the first time. But the third time, filling inputs and clicking submit succeeds. All this is with no code change and same input everytime.